# Issue in React code execution priority

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

as I understand the code execution priority

1- the constructor

```
constructor(props) 
  {
    super(props);
    this.authed = this.props.navigation.getParam('authed', '');
  }
```

2- then the render function

```
render() {
    return ({ this.authed == '' && <this.Nauthedcard /> });
}
```

3- the issue here - it see this.navigation as undefined

```
Nauthedcard()
{
   console.log(this.props.navigation); // makes error (this.props is undefined)

   return(<Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')} rounded small iconRight>
          <Text> Login </Text>
          <Icon type="FontAwesome" name="sign-in" />
        </Button>); // so unfortunately onPress event here makes error with me
}
```

Comment: looks like it should work, are you sure `this.props.navigation` is not `undefined`? Any reason you are attempting to store and not using `state` or it as a prop?  Either way you are storing a reference to `this.props.navigation` so it will mutate the original object with any changes

Comment: this.navigation = this.props.navigation; seems a bit redundant. You can use this.props.navigation in render method.

Comment: @butchyyyy - I did , the same issue

Comment: @EricHasselbring , It's defined in the constructor but not in the Nauthedcard() function

Comment: what I got - it visits the Nauthedcard() function before executing the codes in the constructor , any solution ?

Comment: yes because Nauthedcard is not bound to the context of the class, it cannot access its locals, either bind in the constructor or make it an arrow function `Nauthedcard = () => {}`

Comment: yes `Nauthedcard = () => {} ` solved the issue